# Windows aren't staying in place after closing them

Tags: 16.04, window, bug-reporting, 16.10

I installed 16.04 and upgraded to 16.10 and experienced this on both versions. The default programs' windows don't remember their location. For example, when I open the file explorer or the terminal, the windows both open with different sizes and locations all the way on the right bottom of my screen. I can then center them and resize them, but when I close them and reopen them they are back to the way they started (bottom right of my screen and the wrong size).

If I install a program myself, however, the program's windows remember their location and size.

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Nautilus always opens near top left for me no matter where I place it before exiting. This is on 16.04 upgrade from 14.04.

Comment: This happens for Terminal and Software Center as well for me.

Comment: That happens for my Terminal too, but I don't use Software Center.